# Configuração de Elétrons de um Elemento da Tabela Periódica

Tags: c#

Gostaria de criar um programa que fizesse a distribuição eletrônica dos átomos, porém não sei bem como implementá-la. Ela seria da seguinte maneira? você colocaria o numero atômico e ele te devolveria a distribuição eletrônica (K, L, M, N, O, P, Q).

Pensei em usar if's considerando que as camadas tem um número máximo de elétrons:

```
K = 2
L = 8
M = 18
N = 32
O = 32
P = 18
Q = 8
```

Porém existe 2 regras que são:

1. A última camada não pode ter mais que 8 elétrons
2. A penúltima camada não pode ter mais que 18 elétrons

Estas duas regras bugam toda a minha lógica. A pergunta é: Alguém sabe uma forma melhor de implementar esse projeto?

**Edit:** Consegui uma boa parte agora, porém os números restantes ficam iguais aos do de valência. Alguém pode me ajudar a corrijir esse erro?

```
using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace ConsoleApplication5
   {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

           int z = 53;



            int K = 1, L = 555, M = 555, N = 555, O = 555, P = 555, Q = 555;

            if (z >= 2) { z -= 2; K = 2; } else { K = z; }


            if (z >= 8) { z -= 8; L = 8; }
            if (z < 8) L = z;


            if (z >= 18) { z -= 18; M = 18; }
            if (z <= 8) M = z;


            if (z >= 32) { z -= 32; N = 32; }
            if (z < 32 && z >= 18) { z -= 18; N = 18; }
            if (z <= 8) N = z;


            if (z >= 32) { z -= 32; O = 32; }
            if (z > 32 && z >= 18) { z -= 18; O = 18; }
            if (z <= 8) O = z;


            if (z >= 18) { z -= 18; P = 18; }
            if (z <= 8) P = z;


            if (z >= 8) {z -= 8; Q = 8; }
            if (z <= 8) Q = z;


            Console.WriteLine("Valores:\nK = " + K + "\nL = " + L + "\nM = " + M + "\nN = " + N + "\nO = " + O + "\nP = " + P + "\nQ = " + Q);
            Console.ReadKey(); 

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Poste o que você tem até agora para podermos ter uma base mais sólida para formular uma ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz um código que acho que vai te ajudar.

Eu não testei muito bem, mas já vai servir de base para você.

**Editado:**

```
class Program
{

    enum DefinicaoCamada
    {
        K = 2,
        L = 8,
        M = 18,
        N = 32,
        O = 32,
        P = 18,
        Q = 8
    }

    class Camada
    {
        public DefinicaoCamada defCamada;
        public int eletrons;

        public Camada(DefinicaoCamada defCamada)
        {
            this.defCamada = defCamada;
        }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int totalEletrons = 53;

        Camada ultima = null;

        List<Camada> listaCamadas = new List<Camada>() {
            new Camada(DefinicaoCamada.K),
            new Camada(DefinicaoCamada.L),
            new Camada(DefinicaoCamada.M),
            new Camada(DefinicaoCamada.N),
            new Camada(DefinicaoCamada.O),
            new Camada(DefinicaoCamada.P),
            new Camada(DefinicaoCamada.Q)
        };

        Camada camadaAtual = listaCamadas[0];
        while (totalEletrons > 0)
        {
            if (camadaAtual.eletrons >= (int)camadaAtual.defCamada)
            {
                camadaAtual = listaCamadas[listaCamadas.IndexOf(camadaAtual) + 1];
            }
            else
            {
                camadaAtual.eletrons++;
                totalEletrons--;
                ultima = camadaAtual;
            }
        }

        int dif = 0;

        if (ultima.eletrons > 18)
        {
            dif = ultima.eletrons - 18;
            ultima.eletrons = 18;
            Camada prox = listaCamadas[listaCamadas.IndexOf(ultima) + 1];
            prox.eletrons = dif;
            ultima = prox;
        }

        if (ultima.eletrons > 8 && ultima.eletrons < 18)
        {
            dif = ultima.eletrons - 8;
            ultima.eletrons = 8;
            Camada prox = listaCamadas[listaCamadas.IndexOf(ultima) + 1];
            prox.eletrons = dif;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Valores:");
        foreach (Camada c in listaCamadas)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.defCamada.ToString() + " = " + c.eletrons);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: O problema dessa forma é que ele inflige as duas regras da distribuiçao eletronica =P
Fiz uma ediçao no codigo, o unico problema agora é que as camadas depois da camada de valencia dao o numero da camada de valencia. sabe como corrigir? =P

Comment: Modifiquei o código. Acho que deve estar tudo correto agora.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Eletrons
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Passo 1: Detectar qual a última camada cheia.
            int z = 53, i = 0, somaCamadas = 0;
            var arrayCamadas = new int[] { 2, 8, 18, 32, 32, 18, 8 };

            foreach (var camada in arrayCamadas)
            {
                somaCamadas += camada;
                if (z - somaCamadas <= 0) break;
                i++;
            }

            // Até aqui, i é a última camada preenchida com todos os elétrons.
            // Para o exemplo 53, i deverá ser 3.

            // Passo 2: Construir a lista que será retornada.

            var listaRetorno = new List<int>();
            var eletronsFaltantes = z;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                listaRetorno.Add(arrayCamadas[j]);
                eletronsFaltantes -= arrayCamadas[j];
            }

            // No exemplo, eletronsFaltantes será 25.
            // A regra de conferência para as duas últimas camadas ocorrerá apenas se i for 
            // maior ou igual a 3.

            if (i >= 3)
            {
                if (eletronsFaltantes - 18 > 0)
                {
                    listaRetorno.Add(18);
                    eletronsFaltantes -= 18;
                }
            }

            listaRetorno.Add(eletronsFaltantes);

            listaRetorno.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Para 53, esta solução retornou K = 2, L = 8, M = 18, N = 18, O = 7. Acho que está certo.